# Why does creating a set and getting its len each loop take so much longer than doing it up front?

Tags: python, data-structures

```
m = len(set(nums))
n = len(nums)
ans = 0
for i in range(n):
    s = set()
for j in range(i, n):
    s.add(nums[j])
    ans += len(s) == m
return ans
```

From the above code when I replace `m` with `len(set(nums))` and comparing with `len(s)` then the time limit is exceeding, where `1 <= nums.length <= 1000`.
Could someone explain why?

```
n = len(nums)
ans = 0
for i in range(n):
    s = set()
for j in range(i, n):
    s.add(nums[j])
    if len(s) == len(set(nums)):
        ans += 1
return ans
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: You could put something like "Why does creating a set and getting its len each loop take so much longer than doing it up front?" for the title. Although, that begs the question of why you would expect anything different, since creating a set takes time. Maybe you just didn't realize that? BTW, if it helps, there's a handy Python wiki page: [Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), though it doesn't cover creation/initialization times.

Answer (score 1):

In the above code where `m = len(set(nums))`, you are precalculating the value of `m`. To calculate `m` it take *O(n)* as time complexity, where *n* = no. of elements in `nums`. In the above code the value of `m` is constant.

But in the below code, you are replacing `m` with `len(set(nums))` in for loop. So for every iteration of for loop the value of `m` is getting calculated. It takes *O(n)* as time complexity for every iteration. So, overall it is taking *O(n^2)* as time complexity for calculating `m`.

That's why it is showing time limit exceeded

Comment: I would suggest to explicitly mention that since each loop takes O(n), in total the entire program then takes O(n^2)

Comment: In above code for calculating m, I think inbuilt len functions takes o(1)

Comment: @saiganesh`len` takes O(1), but `set` takes O(n) (best case, potentially worse, up to O(n^2)).